# How to get detailed error message thrown by express in angular

Tags: node.js, angular, http, express, rxjs

I am sending an HTTP request from angular to a node/express API. How do I get the actual error message I send from the node/express API

I am handling my exceptions well when they are thrown in the API but the moment I try to read the message in Angular I only get the name of the type of error I throw. For example, if I throw a 409 the error received by angular is just "Conflict" and does not contain the details I send. Please look at my code below.

I am sending my request as below

```
register(user: UserAccount) {
    return this.http
      .post(`${config.apiUrl}/users/register`, user)
      .pipe(
        map((res: HttpResponse<Response>) => {
          return res;
        }))
      .pipe(catchError(err => this.errorHandler.handleError(err)));
  }
```

My handle error is as below:

```
handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.log(error);
    if (error) {
      let errMessage = '';
      try {
        errMessage = error.message;
      } catch (error) {
        errMessage = error.statusText;
      }
      return throwError(errMessage || error || 'Server error');
    }
    return throwError(error.error || error || 'Server error');
  }
```

This how I am throwing my error when I occurs in my Node/Express API

```
 registerUser (req, res) {
    debug(chalk.blue(`*** insert user`))
    userRepo
      .create(req.body)
      .then(user => {
        debug(chalk.green(`*** Insert User ok!`))
        res.status(200).json({
          status: true,
          error: null,
          user: user
        })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        debug(chalk.red(`*** insertUser error: ${util.inspect(err)}`))
        if (err['type'] && err['type'] === '409') {
          res.status(409).json({
            status: false,
            error: err['message'],
            user: null
          })
        } else {
          res.status(400).json({
            status: false,
            error: err,
            user: null
          })
        }
      })
  }
```

I want to be able to receive the json object with the information about the error but all I am getting when I access the error item is, for example, in the case of raising a 409, I only get 'Conflict'

Answer (score 0):

The response data in case of error is inside the error property of HttpErrorResponse. So you may need to modify the handleError method as below.

```
handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.log(error);
    if (error) {
      let errMessage = '';
      try {
        // error.error holds the json response sent from API. 
        errMessage = JSON.stringify(error.error);
      } catch (error) {
        errMessage = error.statusText;
      }
      return throwError(errMessage || error || 'Server error');
    }
    return throwError(error.error || error || 'Server error');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Server-side express code

```
registerUser(req, res) {
    debug(chalk.blue(`*** insert user`))
    userRepo
        .create(req.body)
        .then(user => {
            /**
             * SUCCESS TO-DO
             * .
             * .
             * .
             * .
             */

            return res.send(200).json(user)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            /**
             * error handler in server
             * FAILURE TO-DO
             * .
             * .
             * .
             */

            if (err['type'] && err['type'] === '409') {
                res.status(409).json({
                    status: false,
                    error: 'some 409 type error',
                    user: null
                })
            } else {
                res.status(400).json({
                    status: false,
                    error: 'some 400 type error',
                    user: null
                })
            }
        })
}
```

Your angular code

```
handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.log(error);
    if (error) {
        let errMessage = '';
        try {
            errMessage = error.message; // <- here is the problem
        } catch (error) {
            errMessage = error.statusText;
        }
        return throwError(errMessage || error || 'Server error');
    }
    return throwError(error.error || error || 'Server error');
}
```

---

Firstly, if I may rename your `HttpErrorResponse` object as `http_error` as it is too generic. However, the trick lies in reading from the `error` key of the `http_error` object, and not from the `message` key.

### Client-side error handler(angular)

```
handleError(http_error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    // {status: false, error: 'some 409/400 type error', user: null }
    const errMessage = http_error.error;
    /* TO-DO STUFF */
    return throwError(errMessage || 'Server error');
}
```